# how to sort array of object by its value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I have array responsive and I want to sort my array based on the breakpoint variable in the object inside the responsive array. How can I do it?

```
var responsive = [
    {
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
            c: 300
        }
    },
    {
        breakpoint: 780,
        settings: {
            c: 180
        }
    },
    {
        breakpoint: 1400,
        settings: {
            c: 0
        }
    }
];
```

I tried responsive.sort() but still not working? How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the `sort()` method with your own custom logic to specify which property of the array's child object to sort by. Try this:

```js
var responsive = [{
  breakpoint: 1200,
  settings: {
    c: 300
  }
},{
  breakpoint: 780,
  settings: {
    c: 180
  }
},{
  breakpoint: 1400,
  settings: {
    c: 0
  }
}];

responsive.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.breakpoint > b.breakpoint;
});

console.dir(responsive);
```

Note that the above is an ascending sort. If you need descending, swap `>` for a `<`.

Comment: your sort function is not symetrically in the form of `fn(a, b) === -fn(b, a)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
responsive.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.breakpoint < b.breakpoint;
});
```